# Regular trees $T_n$ and their automorphism groups

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $T_n$ be the regular tree of the valency $n>2$.

It is true that $T_n$ is a vertex and edge transitive graph?

Comment: What precisely is a vertex- (resp. edge-) transitive graph in this context?  I understand it to mean that the automorphism group is transitive on the vertices (resp. edges), but that doesn't work in this context, since some vertices are leaves, and some of degree $n$.

Comment: Are these infinite trees?

Comment: @saulspatz in the regular trees there is no leaf. Actually they are infinite.

Comment: @Jivid Thank you, that makes sense.  I found a definition of a regular finite tree on the Internet: all non-leaves have the same degree, but it didn't discuss transitivity.